# SQL Server: select based on the latest id in a many to n:m relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

What i need to do is select the comment details and the last action taken on the comment; I have 3 tables:

Comment

```
CommentID, commentText, userID, date_posted
```

Action

```
ActionID, action_taken,userID,date_actioned
```

and CommentJoinAction

```
id,ActionID,CommentID
```

There can be one comment, but many actions on the comment.

my SQL is looking something like:

```
Select /*snip comment details and such*/
From Comment
Inner Join (select max(actionid) from commentjoinaction) as cja on /*blah cause you know from reading this, it won't work*/
```

So what is it that I can do so that I always pick up the latest commentAction for the comments.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT 
/*Select desired fields*/
FROM Comments AS C
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    CommentID
                    ,MAX(ActionID) AS ActionID
                FROM CommentJoinAction
                GROUP BY CommentID
            )AS CJA
        ON C.CommentID = CJA.CommentID
        INNER JOIN ACTION AS A
            ON CJA.ActionID = A.ActionID
```

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly what i was looking for.  I was on the road to this but just didn't manage to complete it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.commentText, t.action_taken
    FROM (SELECT c.commentText, a.action_taken,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CommentID ORDER BY a.date_actioned DESC) AS RowNum
              FROM Comment c
                  INNER JOIN CommentJoinAction cja
                      ON c.CommentID = cja.CommentID
                  INNER JOIN Action a
                      ON cja.ActionID = a.ActionID
          ) t
    WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select C.*, A.* from Comment C
inner join 
(
    select CommentID, Max(ActionID) as LatestActionID from CommentJoinAction
    group by CommentID
) CJA on C.CommentID = CJA.CommentID
inner join Action A on CJA.LatestActionID = A.ActionID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the actionID

```
select c.*, (
  select max(actionID) 
  from CommentJoinAction cja 
  where cja.commentID = c.commentID
) as maxActionID
from Comment c
```

Or if you want all the Action fields:

```
select c.*, a.*
from Comment c 
inner join Action a 
  on a.actionID =     (
   select max(actionID) 
   from CommentJoinAction 
   where commentID = c.commentID
)
```